# how can i convert this lines of mysql query to mssql-server query?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to make a function but i don know to convert this MySQL query to MSSQL server query

```
 SET @cut = (SELECT IFNULL(MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(`StudentID`,16) AS UNSIGNED)),0)
    FROM `students` 
    WHERE SUBSTRING(`StudentID`,1,15) = CONCAT('STUDENTID',DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(),'%m%d%y')));

    SET @max = (SELECT @cut  + 1);

    SET @id = (CONCAT('STUDENTID',DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(),'%m%d%y'),@max));

    RETURN  @id ;
```

Comment: Have you tried to solve this problem yourself already?  Stack Overflow is a not a free code writing service.

Comment: Apart from Tim's comment, DDL always helps

Comment: i have but i am not very familiar on some mssql query, sorry for bad english

Comment: Then, please, publish your code and explain where you are stuck and what is the error message or where the code stops

Comment: In any case, I would recommend you an incremental process... First issue I see @cut variable needs to be defined in SQL Server but... you must publish the full steps as it is possible that you are publishing only part of the code and some people be stuck in something that you did not published. It is because that you need to publish all relevant code in order to motivate people to help you

Comment: The use of backticks to delimit table names suggests you are using mysql. You won't get far in the development world if you don't know your environment and which tools you are using.

Answer (score 0):

There is no type such as `unsigned` in T-SQL. So you should it check manually. Your T-SQL should like this:

```
DECLARE @cut INT, @max INT, @id int;
SELECT @cut = ISNULL( MAX( CAST( SUBSTRING(StudentID, 1, 16))), 0)
FROM Students
WHERE SUBSTRING(StudentID,1,15) = CONCAT(STUDENTID, convert(varchar, getdate(), 110));
SET @max = (SELECT @cut  + 1);


SET @id = (CONCAT('STUDENTID', convert(varchar, getdate(), 110),@max));

RETURN  @id ;
```

To check manually whether the number is positive:

```
IF @cut < 0
    THROW 50000, '@cut should be positive number', 1
```